# pass curosr variable to subquery in cirsor iterating loop

Tags: plsql

1 what is my purpose:

```
I try to get two person from each department with highest salary.
```

2 how I try to achieve it:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE empl_table IS TABLE OF employees.employee_id%type INDEX BY binary_integer;
  empl empl_table;
  CURSOR departmennts_id IS 
    SELECT department_id FROM departments; 
BEGIN  

FOR depart_row IN departmennts_id  
loop
  SELECT employee_id BULK COLLECT into empl 
  FROM  
    (
      SELECT employee_id
      FROM employees
      where DEPARTMENT_ID= depart_row.department_id
      ORDER BY salary DESC
    )
WHERE ROWNUM<3;
END loop;
END;
```

3 where is the problem:

```
where DEPARTMENT_ID= depart_row.department_id
```

When I change depart_row.department_id for fixed id number(ex. 80)
query works. If I use depart_row.department_id empl.count is 0.

Where I am making mistake?

Comment: Change the `departmennts_id` cursor to `SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID FROM DEPARTMENT WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID = 80` and re-run the whole thing. What happens?

Comment: How about using Oracle Analytical Functions RANK in this case. RANK by DEPT and then filter for RANK < 3. But if you can't analytical functions, then can you put some data in sqlfiddle.com to see it. There could be issue with extra spaces or something.

Comment: @BobJarvis when I use your solution  empl.count=2 (what is correct result) but when I use put_line(depart_row.department_id) in loop for it shows me corret departments ids. I am confused :(

Comment: @Sandeep I will try to use your's solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each iteration of your outer cursor you're putting rows into EMPL_TABLE. Each time that the code loops back for another department_id and then re-executes the inner SELECT it ***replaces the contents*** of the collection. Thus, if the LAST department seen by the outer cursor happens to have no employees associated with it, you end up with an empty collection.

Your best bet is to eliminate the separate cursor on DEPARTMENTS and just use a single cursor that does everything you want, as in:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID,
               SALARY,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER
                 (PARTITION BY DEPARTMENT_ID
                  ORDER BY SALARY DESC) AS EMP_RANK
          FROM EMPLOYEES
          ORDER BY DEPARTMENT_ID, EMP_RANK)
  WHERE EMP_RANK < 3
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/087d6/1).

Share and enjoy.